# How to parse a continuous multipart response in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, multipart, boundary

I'm creating a tool that needs to consume a Security System API. I can't give much information about it but as the API documentation explains:

> A stream of events data will be sent using HTTP Multipart x-mixed-replace transmission. The response data stream is continuous.
>
> Each event is separated by the multipart boundary --DummyBoundary.

From what I understood with some network sniffing tools, whenever an event happens, this stream returns data related to that but how can I read this data into variables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try *multer* library. More details [here](https://github.com/expressjs/multer)